# Unable to reach VirtualBox RHEL 7 guest from host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I had a RHEL 7.2 VM working using qemu/libvirtd management, and needed to bring it up under VirtualBox instead. I converted the .qcow2 disk image to .vdi, and mostly the image comes up fine.

Now I'm trying to get connectivity to the machine.

I added VBox adapter 1 as a Host-only adapter 'vboxnet0', and adapter 2 as NAT.

I configured the vm with a static IP address 172.20.254.39. I see the vboxnet0 interface on my host and can ping it.

I can ssh out from the guest VM, and reach other network addresses. They get routed through the NAT interface.

But I can't ping or ssh from my host to the VM.

Traceroute shows pings attempting to be routed to the correct gateway address for vboxnet0, 172.20.254.1, but returns !H host unreachable for 172.20.254.39.

I know most of this stuff gets configured if I do a fresh install under VirtualBox, but I'm having to reconfigure it manually after porting the image from qemu.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ifconfig -a` on both the host and vm?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall, it's likely blocking the ingress of your SSH and pings.  Are you trying to connect to SSH via root?  That's disabled by RH, you need to enable that.